# A way to decrease power of active and owner keys of account?

Tags: permissions, multisig

I'm reading this article: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/accounts-and-permissions

1. It's allowed to add many owners to single EOS account, right?
2. It's allowed to have many active keys for single EOS account, right?

Imagine I have EOS contract created by EOS account with 2 owners and 2 active keys.

- Every owner, active keys have weight 1
- The threshold is set to 2.

Does it mean that single EOS owner / active key won't be able to do anything with contract? right?

Would a single active key be able to send proposal to eosio.msig contract? Another active key would catch it up and maybe sign.

Comment: If  you have created 3-4 or may be  more accounts using same keys.Your wallet may  be same but your accounts are treated differently. And for your eosio.msig double can you explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. If all permissions on the account have threshold of 2+, and all keys have weight of 1, no one actor (alone) can perform any action on the account.

Take a look at the [eosio.prods](https://bloks.io/account/eosio.prods) permissions, you'll notice the active key have threshold of 15 and there are 21 keys with weight of 1. Might not be the best example, as it is a special account with null-ed owner key, but I like it as an example of advanced permissions.